# Changes in HTML using Internet Explorer developer tools

Tags: ie-developer-tools

How do I can determine whether users make changes using IE8 developer tools?
Are there are any javascript events?

Answer (score 0):

The IE developer tools don't fire any specific events for when a user alters the page via the developer tools. In IE9+ mutation events will fire whenever the DOM is altered be it by the tools or your code.

What are you concerned that the user would do?